# Splitting data frame into 100 buckets and after split output should contain the values 25, 50, 75 in those 100 values

Tags: r

I want to split the data frame into 100 buckets(to show these 100 values in a graph) and in those 100 values should contains 25,50,75 values(25, 50, 75 values should not missed in any case in those 100 values).
But the problem is if I pass a data frame with less than 100 values I was not getting 25, 50, 75 values in the output with the below code.

Below is the data frame with less than 100 rows for which ntile() is failing to give 25, 50,75 values in **output_df**.

```
   df <- data.frame(usr_thp =
c(564.4733658,
642.1442142,
751.2999088,
767.3654291,
1177.598259,
1235.646466,
1442.834145,
1799.008496,
2136.925833,
2183.736126,
2251.76611,
2565.485513,
2791.037469,
2817.081995,
2817.169915,
3090.413274,
3452.138419,
3792.897529,
3813.101734,
4364.9713,
4517.857481,
4690.001855,
4737.380507,
4830.179267,
4906.446091,
5437.591944,
5465.150774,
5614.31162,
5862.69037,
5874.591271,
5956.859055,
5990.081847,
6104.084737,
6136.593924,
6156.072481,
6322.750252,
6453.179695,
6525.322676,
6549.369024,
6553.52475,
6646.479767,
6903.330889,
7044.806765,
7089.765708,
7299.0698,
7658.256263,
7668.333518,
7683.219606,
7884.227521,
7976.371067,
8034.630945,
8153.86454,
8155.635059,
8348.227014,
8980.884306,
9223.800387,
9410.946208,
9478.217587,
9801.870998,
10023.12566,
10553.40744,
10583.41615,
11625.85716,
11975.92464,
12304.78107,
13511.52622,
13681.24599,
14783.2377,
15560.06325,
15773.75931,
16202.474,
17118.28004,
17829.97004,
18139.05167,
19044.59533,
20792.20441,
21081.17953,
21585.34027,
22058.40687,
28447.04231), count_no = c(1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,
15,16,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,28,29,30,31,32,34,35,36,38,39,40,41,42,
44,45,46,48,49,50,51,52,54,55,56,58,59,60,61,62,64,65,66,68,69,70,71,
72,74,75,76,78,79,80,81,82,84,85,86,88,89,90,91,92,94,95,96,98,99,100))


N_QUANTILES <- 100
QUARTILES <- c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75) * N_QUANTILES
    
    output_df <- df %>%
            dplyr::select(scenario='usr_thp') %>%
            dplyr::mutate(quantile = dplyr::ntile(scenario,N_QUANTILES))
```

I have to show  **output_df** values in a graph and it should contains 25,50,75 values. But here if you observe the output 25,50,75 values are not part of it.

Comment: Perhaps show an example where the problem actually exists? I can't follow what you are asking here.   Please explain and show an example of " but the output missing the quantiles 25, 50, 75 some times but those quantiles should not be missed at anytime"

Comment: Please run the given code on the given data frame. I have given the real data.
The output should contains the values 25,50,75 but after I applied ntile() method those values are missing in output. I have to keep those values in output because in the second block of code I am only taking those values to display those values as a table.

Comment: ran it and I don't see the problem you are talking about. Also `output_df` does not contain 100 points. It contains 80, but it does contain rows for quantile = 25, 50, and 75

Comment: just modified the data frame, please try now

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to identify the data points that are closest to the 25th, 50th, 75th percentiles?

Comment: I have modified my post for better understanding

Comment: How are your 80 rows supposed to go into 100 buckets? Maybe you want 4 buckets and to look at the first values in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th of those?

Comment: I can't decide the data frame rows, is there any alternative to do that if datafame contains less than 100 rows

Comment: Depends, what is the actual goal here? I think your question is following a path that doesn't make sense -- you can't divide 80 elements into 100 bins without either repetition or skipping bins and there's not a programming answer that can change that. I suspect you want either "What elements are closest to 0.25 / 0.5 / 0.75" or "What interpolated points are at 0.25/0.5/0.75" (which I answered below)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df %>%
  summarize(quantile = paste0( "Q",1:3, "(", scales::percent(c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75)), ")"),
    value = quantile(usr_thp, c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = quantile, values_from = value)


# A tibble: 1 × 3
  `Q1(25%)` `Q2(50%)` `Q3(75%)`
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     4480.     6600.    10156.
```

Comment: not exactly,
step1: 
Please execute below code on the given df and observe the output, in that output 25, 50, 75 is missing, I have to make sure those values are not missed in the output_df that's it. (output is fine with below code only thing is it should not miss those point in any case)
N_QUANTILES <- 100
QUARTILES <- c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75) * N_QUANTILES
    output_df <- df %>%
            dplyr::select(scenario='usr_thp') %>%
            dplyr::mutate(quantile = dplyr::ntile(scenario,N_QUANTILES)) 

this code is working absolutely fine.